# django ajax MultiValueDictKeyError

Tags: ajax, django

I am receiving this error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /orders/ajax/add_order_line
"'cart'"
```

Here is my script

```
var cart = {
    0: {
        id: "1",
        quantity: 50
    }
}

$.ajax({
    url: myURL,
    type: "post",
    data: {cart: cart},
    success: function() {},
    error: function(){}
});
```

Meanwhile in my django views, the error was found in this line:

```
def something(request):
    cart = request.POST['cart']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `get` method of multivaluedict

```
request.POST.get('cart')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is a nested array, so you can't send it using the default default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type.

You can send the data as json:

```
$.ajax({
    url: myURL,
    type: "post",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({cart: cart}),
    success: function() {},
    error: function(){}
});
```

Then in your view, you have to load the json string from `request.body` instead of using `request.POST` (which is for form-encoded data only).

```
import json

def my_view(reqest):
    data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    cart = data.get('cart')
```